# drupal module for uploading to s3

Tags: 7, files

originally posted on stackexchange.  Didn't get any replies.  Then I recently found out there's a specific drupal stackexchange so here i am reposting.  TIA!

I have a drupal site and I plan to serve static site files directly from s3 (rewrite). I need to provide a way for the content manager to upload his images directly to s3 from the drupal admin UI so he doesn't have to send it to me to upload via s3cmd or the aws console. Can anyone recommend a module or method for this?

I've tried s3fs however mounting a fuse s3 filesystem and serving from it was painfully slow. If it worked drupal would think the files are all local and i'd be set.

I found this but not sure if it will get the job done for me: https://drupal.org/project/storage_api

I need a module that would allow the drupal admin UI user to graphically browse for a file (image for instance) to upload to the s3 bucket i intend to serve from.

Comment: You shouldn't repost, instead try migrating your previous post if that option is availble.

Comment: I know.. but it's not.  it would be nice if it can be moved but that option isn't there.  Which left me no other option but to post here.  Still no replies though.  I am having some luck with the storage_api.  I was able to get the module installed and the s3 bucket configured.  not much documentation so i have to go by trial and error.  attempting to get files uploaded to s3 via the admin ui and served directly from s3 after.

Comment: I voted that your question on stackexchange would be closed and hopefully it will be migrated to this site instead=)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

storage_api is the right module for seamlessly transferring data such that the user's upload lands first on the servers local filesystem and by rules can have it automatically propagate to any number of containers (S3, Cloud Files etc..)  And even more you can control the priority in which the files are served from the site simply by ordering them in prefered manner.  the URLs will change automatically. pretty slick.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good blog post about using S3 as a media storage for Drupal: http://davidcsonka.com/blog/how-use-amazon-s3-store-your-drupal-website-files

Also, you may consider SaaS solutions, such as Filepicker, Cloudinary or Uploadcare. The latter has an open-source module for Drupal integration: https://github.com/uploadcare/uploadcare-drupal

Comment: I think I'm ok with storage_api.  The only problem is with the dynamic files generated by drupal css/js etc.  Currently the only setting i can see for destination of these files is on the localdisk.  There's no way of choosing a storage class instead.